# How to typecast for mysql in()

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I'm building a php script that creates a query string like,

```
$products = array(873, 874, 875);
$sql = 'select * from product_thumbnails where product in (' . implode($products, ', ') . ')';
```

which creates a query like

```
'select * from product_thumbnails where product in (873, 874, 875)'
```

The datatype for product is int. Are the params to the in() function treated as strings? If so, that would leave mysql to compare ints to strings and thus probably lead to a slow query as the app grows. Is there a way to typecast the params or to tell mysql to treat them as ints? Or is mysql smart enough to juggle this on its own?

**Edit**

Thanks much to Jerodev and jilesh for the answer- Mysql will treat these as ints. If you wanted a string instead, just use quotes inside the query string like

```
' in ("stringtype", "stringtype") '
```

Comment: No, these are seen as integers, strings would be between `"`. Also, yes, mysql is smart enough to cast these on its own.

Comment: Yes if you use in and there is string then you have to done like select * from product_thumbnails where product in ('one', 'two', 'three'). And yes there is function name CAST() in mysql where you can assign datatype to any of your value. But here this is fine for integer also you use query on same way as i.e :   select * from product_thumbnails where product in ('873', '874', '875'). This thing working fine too.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL syntax...  When expecting a number, you can provide a number `123` *or* a string `"123"`.

When expecting a string, you can provide either, *but* when comparing a `VARCHAR` to an unquoted number (`123`), it goes to the extra effort of converting the `VARCHAR` to numeric, which often gives you the wrong answer:  `"abc"` is treated as `0`, or at least something confusing: `"123abc"` is treated as `123`.